# MySQL how to reverse where?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table like this

| id | path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | / |
| 2 | /a/ |
| 3 | /a/b/ |
| 4 | /a/b/c/ |
| 5 | /a/b/c/d |

When I use a path (e.g., path = '/a/b/c/') in the `where` clause, I would like to retrieve the children of this path.

e.g.:

id path

| id | path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | / |
| 2 | /a/ |
| 3 | /a/b/ |
| 4 | /a/b/c/ |

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`instr`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  INSTR('/a/b/c', path) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `LIKE` for find child or parent in next way:

```sql
-- select childs of /a/b/

select *
from paths 
where path like ('/a/b/%');

-- select parents of /a/b/

select *
from paths 
where '/a/b/' like concat(path,'%');
```

[Test SQL LIKE online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/fec8872fa8b8818416aeea96bbb37234/)

Comment: this also works appreciated thanks